# why when we use && or || between two logical vectors return just 1 element

Tags: r, logic, logical-operators

I am new to R and I am trying to understand why when we use && or || between two logical vectors it returns just 1 element

```
a<-c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
b<-c(FALSE,FALSE,FALSE)
a&&b
```

Why doesn’t this return a logical vector?

Comment: `&&` and `||` are not vectorized . If you want to do element wise comparisons on two vectors use `&` and `|`. For more see `?Logic`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of logical operators in R, vectorized and not vectorized.  The `&&` and `||` are not vectorized.  They are intended to be used with single `TRUE` or `FALSE` values on either side, and short-circuit evaluation is used:  so if the result is known after evaluating the left-hand side, the right-hand side will not be evaluated.  For example,

```
FALSE && fn()
```

is `FALSE` regardless of the value of `fn()`, so it won't be evaluated.  This is useful in tests where the right-hand side might give an error, e.g.

```
if (is.numeric(x) && x + 1 > 0)
```

since `x + 1 > 0` will give an error if `x` is not numeric.

The `&` and `|` operators are the vectorized versions.  They take vectors of logicals on both sides, and return a vector of logical values.  They will always evaluate both sides.  They need to do this in examples like

```
FALSE & fn()
```

because even though the result is known to be false, the length may change depending on the result of calling `fn()`.

In upcoming versions of R, it will be an error to use something like your example, because it doesn't make sense to use `&&` with length 3 vectors.